# Display a fading jQuery Alert Message without using traditional javascript alert-box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following form, my question is  implementing a fadding JQuery Alert message without using the normal js alertBox

**the Html Form**

```
      <form name="userLogin" action="success.php" onsubmit="validateInputField()" method="post">
         UserName: <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
         password: <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
         <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
```

**javaScript code**

```
<script>
    function validateInputField() {

         var x = document.forms["userLogin"]["username"].value;
         var y = document.forms["userLogin"]["pwd"].value;

         if (x == null || x == "") {

         alert("Name must be filled out");

    return false;
    }
          if (y == null || y == "") {

         alert("Password must be filled out");

    return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can try something like this-> http://demos.9lessons.info/jnotification/index.php

Comment: if you are using `jquery` already, why not use `jqueryui`? https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: check this: http://jsfiddle.net/sunnypmody/XDaEk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add a `div` and display your error message within that `div` and use `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` to animate the same.

```js
function validateInputField() {

  var x = document.forms["userLogin"]["username"].value;
  var y = document.forms["userLogin"]["pwd"].value;

  if (x == null || x == "") {
  $(".alert").find('.message').text("Name must be filled out");
  $(".alert").fadeIn("slow",function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
        $(".alert").fadeOut("slow");
      },4000);
    });
      

    return false;
  }
  if (y == null || y == "") {

    $(".alert").find('.message').text("Name must be filled out");
    $(".alert").fadeIn("slow",function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
        $(".alert").fadeOut("slow");
      },4000);
    });
    return false;
  }
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.alert {
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  padding:20px;
}
.message {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="userLogin" action="success.php" onsubmit="validateInputField()" method="post">
  UserName:
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">password:
  <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<div class="alert hide">
  <div class="message">
  </div>
</div>
```

**To be more optimized**

```js
function validateInputField() {

  var x = document.forms["userLogin"]["username"].value;
  var y = document.forms["userLogin"]["pwd"].value;

  if (x == null || x == "") {
    showAlert("Name must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
  if (y == null || y == "") {
    showAlert("Password must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
}

function showAlert(message) {
  $(".alert").find('.message').text(message);
  $(".alert").fadeIn("slow", function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".alert").fadeOut("slow");
    }, 4000);
  });
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.alert {
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  padding:20px;
}
.message {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="userLogin" action="success.php" onsubmit="validateInputField()" method="post">
  UserName:
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">password:
  <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<div class="alert hide">
  <div class="message">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: works well on the code snippet. let me try it out in my editor. thanks champ

Comment: Anytime.. Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Why not [make your own?](https://jsfiddle.net/3wta1k2n/2/)

A simple `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` can create a really cool "alert-box" and is super easy to use :)

Answer (score 1):

**Login Page:-**

First You have to Create Your `Login Code` & at Last use `header()` with `URL get Variable`.

```
<?php
header('Location:view.php?status=login');
?>
```

**Dashboard Page:-**

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['status']) == 'login'){
     echo '<div class="alert alert-success">
        Login Successfully !!!
           </div>';
}
?>
```

**jQuery Part:-**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" rel="stylesheet"> 
$('document').ready(function(){ 
$(".alert").fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(5000); 
}); 
</script>
```